# Markov chain generator

Tags: python, generator, markov-chains, markov

The generator should take a starting point (an integer). With each pass of the resultant generator object to next, a random step from the last point returned (or the starting point if no point has yet been returned) should be performed. The result of this step should be returned after the step is taken.

```
import random

def markov(start: int):
  for i in range (1):
     yield random.randint(i-1, i+1)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why are you looping over `range(1)`?

Comment: Replace `for ...` with `while True:` maybe? And increase the initial value in every step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Assuming a step-size of 1 (in either direction), you should be able to get rid of the `i` counter altogether:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>>
>>> def markov(start: int):
...     location = start
...     while True:
...         yield location
...         location += random.randint(-1, 1)
...
>>>
>>> gen = markov(5)
>>> next(gen)
5
>>> next(gen)
6
>>> next(gen)
5
>>> next(gen)
6
>>> next(gen)
7
>>> next(gen)
6
>>> next(gen)
5
>>> next(gen)
4
>>> next(gen)
4
>>> next(gen)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I introduced a count for easy testing, but you could just go with an endless loop. This will go 1 back or further than the last step or stay at the last step.

```
import random

def markov(start: int):
  step = start
  count = 0
  while count<20:
     step = random.randint(step-1, step+1)
     yield step
     count += 1
```

You can test if this is what you want by `list(markov(1))` for example. If you always want it to move, I would replace `step = random.randint(step-1, step+1)` with `step = random.choice([step-1, step+1])`.